# How many days it take to reflect income tax paid on form 26as?

Tags: income-tax, india

Today, I have paid my payable amount of income tax through Government Website as Self Assessment Tax using Chalan 280. 
Now, I want to file my ITR but same tax paid amount is not available in FORM 26AS...How many days it take to reflect in form 26as...

Answer (score 1):

It takes anywhere from few days to month.

You need not wait. You can manually add the BSR, date, Serial number and file the returns.